# How to recursively add, subtract, divide or multiply the numbers in calculator in android?

Tags: android, calculator

I am developing Calculator app for android and having novice user, facing little problems.
What I am trying to implement is as follows:
When user hits 2 + 3 = 5
When again **user hits = sign only**, it should display 8 (i.e. 5 + 3 = 8)
Currently I am following the below approach to do my work:

```
private TextView txtCalc=null;
private double num = 0;
num = num + Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());

String txt = Double.toString(num);
txtCalc.setText(txt);
```

Then depending on the operator (+, - ,etc) entered by the user, it performs the mathematical operation.

Any Suggestions?
Code snippet would be greatly helpful if anyone can provide it.
For @Sandy: here is my complete code:

```
    public class Calculator extends Activity {
    private final String SDK_VERSION = "1";
    private final int MENUITEM_CLOSE = 300;

    /*
    * Edit Text and Button object initialization for simple
    * calculator design.
    */
    private TextView txtCalc=null;
    private Button btnZero=null;
    private Button btnOne=null;
    private Button btnTwo=null;
    private Button btnThree=null;
    private Button btnFour=null;
    private Button btnFive=null;
    private Button btnSix=null;
    private Button btnSeven=null;
    private Button btnEight=null;
    private Button btnNine=null;
    private Button btnPlus=null;
    private Button btnMinus=null;
    private Button btnMultiply=null;
    private Button btnDivide=null;
    private Button btnEquals=null;
    private Button btnAC=null;
    private Button btnDecimal=null;
    private Button btnPT=null;
    private Button btnMR=null;
    private Button btnMM=null;
    private Button btnMP=null;
    private Button btnCE=null;
    private Button btnPerc=null;
    private Button btnSqrRoot=null;
    private Button btnGT=null;

    private double num = 0;
    private double memNum = 0;
    private int operator = 1;

    // 0 = nothing, 1 = plus, 2 = minus, 3 =
    // multiply, 4 = divide

    private boolean readyToClear = false;
    private boolean hasChanged = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

    this.setTitle("Dual Memory Calculator");

    initControls();
    initScreenLayout();
    reset();
    }

    private void initScreenLayout() {

    /*
    * The following three command lines you can use depending
    * upon the emulator device you are using.
    */

    // 320 x 480 (Tall Display - HVGA-P) [default]
    // 320 x 240 (Short Display - QVGA-L)
    // 240 x 320 (Short Display - QVGA-P)

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    // this.showAlert(dm.widthPixels +" "+ dm.heightPixels, dm.widthPixels
    // +" "+ dm.heightPixels, dm.widthPixels +" "+ dm.heightPixels, false);

    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int width = dm.widthPixels;

    if (height < 400 || width < 300) {
    txtCalc.setTextSize(20);

    }

    if (width < 300) {
    /*btnPT.setTextSize(18);
    btnMR.setTextSize(18);
    btnMP.setTextSize(18);
    btnMM.setTextSize(18);
    btnCE.setTextSize(18);
    btnDivide.setTextSize(18);
    btnPlus.setTextSize(18);
    btnMinus.setTextSize(18);
    btnMultiply.setTextSize(18);
    btnEquals.setTextSize(18);
    btnGT.setTextSize(18);
    btnPerc.setTextSize(18);
    btnAC.setTextSize(18);
    btnSqrRoot.setTextSize(18);
    btnNine.setTextSize(18);
    btnEight.setTextSize(18);
    btnSeven.setTextSize(18);
    btnSix.setTextSize(18);
    btnFive.setTextSize(18);
    btnFour.setTextSize(18);
    btnThree.setTextSize(18);
    btnTwo.setTextSize(18);
    btnOne.setTextSize(18);
    btnZero.setTextSize(18);
    btnDecimal.setTextSize(18);*/
    }

    btnZero.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnOne.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnThree.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnFour.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnFive.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnSix.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnSeven.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnEight.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnNine.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnGT.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnDecimal.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    btnMP.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnMM.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnMR.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnPT.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnCE.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    btnAC.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnPerc.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnSqrRoot.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    private void initControls() {
    txtCalc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCalc);
    btnZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
    btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    btnTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
    btnThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnThree);
    btnFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFour);
    btnFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFive);
    btnSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSix);
    btnSeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSeven);
    btnEight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEight);
    btnNine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNine);
    btnPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    btnMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
    btnMultiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply);
    btnDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);
    btnEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEquals);
    btnAC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAC);
    btnDecimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecimal);
    btnPT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPT);
    btnMR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMR);
    btnMM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMM);
    btnMP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMP);
    btnCE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCE);
    btnPerc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPerc);
    btnSqrRoot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSqrRoot);
    btnGT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGT);


    //txtCalc.setOnKeyListener(new On)
    btnZero.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(0);
    }
    });
    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(1);
    }
    });
    btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(2);
    }
    });
    btnThree.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(3);
    }
    });
    btnFour.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(4);
    }
    });
    btnFive.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(5);
    }
    });
    btnSix.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(6);
    }
    });
    btnSeven.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(7);
    }
    });
    btnEight.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(8);
    }
    });
    btnNine.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleNumber(9);
    }
    });
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleEquals(1);
    }
    });
    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleEquals(2);
    }
    });
    btnMultiply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleEquals(3);
    }
    });
    btnDivide.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleEquals(4);
    }
    });
    btnEquals.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    /*String tempNum = txtCalc.getText().toString().trim();
    Double tempDoubleNum = Double.valueOf(tempNum);
    //num = tempDoubleNum + num;
    if(!hasChanged){
            if(txtCalc.getText().toString() != ""){

                switch(operator){

                case 0:
                    handleEquals(0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    num = tempDoubleNum + Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
                    handleEquals(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    num = tempDoubleNum - Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
                    handleEquals(2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    num = tempDoubleNum * Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
                    handleEquals(3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    num = tempDoubleNum / Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
                    handleEquals(4);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } */
    handleEquals(0);
    }
    });
    btnAC.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    reset();
    }
    });
    btnDecimal.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleDecimal();
    }
    });
    btnGT.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handlePlusMinus();
    }
    });
    btnPT.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    memNum = 0;
    }
    });
    btnMR.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    setValue(Double.toString(memNum));
    }
    });
    btnMM.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    memNum = memNum
    - Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
    operator = 0;
    }
    });
    btnMP.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    memNum = memNum
    + Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
    operator = 0;
    }
    });
    btnCE.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    handleBackspace();
    }
    });
    btnSqrRoot.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    setValue(Double.toString(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(txtCalc
    .getText().toString()))));
    }
    });
    btnPerc.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    setValue(Double.toString(num
    * (0.01 * Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText()
    .toString()))));
    }
    });

    txtCalc.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int i, android.view.KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    // txtCalc.append("["+Integer.toString(keyCode)+"]");

    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
    handleNumber(0);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
    handleNumber(1);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
    handleNumber(2);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
    handleNumber(3);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4:
    handleNumber(4);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5:
    handleNumber(5);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6:
    handleNumber(6);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7:
    handleNumber(7);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8:
    handleNumber(8);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9:
    handleNumber(9);
    break;

    case 43:
    handleEquals(1);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_EQUALS:
        hasChanged = false;
        if(!hasChanged && txtCalc.getText().toString()!= ""){
            String strNum = txtCalc.getText().toString();
            Double tmpNum = Double.valueOf(strNum);
            handleEquals(keyCode);
        }
    handleEquals(0);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MINUS:
    handleEquals(2);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PERIOD:
    handleDecimal();
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C:
    reset();
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SLASH:
    handleEquals(4);
    break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
    return false;
    }
    }

    return true;
    }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,1, MENUITEM_CLOSE, "Close");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENUITEM_CLOSE:
    finish();
    break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
    {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
        BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
        return rounded.doubleValue();
    }

    private void handleEquals(int newOperator) {
    if (hasChanged) {
    switch (operator) {
    case 1:
        num = num + Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
        break;
    case 2:
        num = num - Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
        break;
    case 3:
        num = num * Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
        String strNum = null; 
        strNum = Double.toString(num);
        if(strNum.contains("E")){
        strNum = strNum.substring(0, 6) + strNum.substring(strNum.indexOf("E"));
        }
        Log.i("MULTIPLICATION","Checking Precision");
        System.out.println("New StrNum is: " + strNum);
        num = Double.valueOf(strNum);
        break;
    case 4:
        num = num / Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
        break;
    }

    String txt = Double.toString(num);
    txtCalc.setText(txt);
    //txtCalc.setSelection(txt.length());

    readyToClear = true;
    hasChanged = false;
    }

    operator = newOperator;
    }

    private void handleNumber(int num) {
    if (operator == 0)
    reset();

    String txt = txtCalc.getText().toString();
    if (readyToClear) {
    txt = "";
    readyToClear = false;
    } else if (txt.equals("0"))
    txt = "";

    txt = txt + Integer.toString(num);

    txtCalc.setText(txt);
    //txtCalc.setSelection(txt.length());

    hasChanged = true;
    }

    private void setValue(String value) {
    if (operator == 0)
    reset();

    if (readyToClear) {
    readyToClear = false;
    }

    txtCalc.setText(value);
    //txtCalc.setSelection(value.length());

    hasChanged = true;
    }

    private void handleDecimal() {
    if (operator == 0)
    reset();

    if (readyToClear) {
    txtCalc.setText("0.");
    //txtCalc.setSelection(2);
    readyToClear = false;
    hasChanged = true;
    } else {
    String txt = txtCalc.getText().toString();

    if (!txt.contains(".")) {
    txtCalc.append(".");
    hasChanged = true;
    }
    }
    }

    private void handleBackspace() {
    if (!readyToClear) {
    String txt = txtCalc.getText().toString();
    if (txt.length() > 0) {
    txt = txt.substring(0, txt.length() - 1);
    if (txt.equals(""))
    txt = "0";

    txtCalc.setText(txt);
//  txtCalc.setSelection(txt.length());
    }
    }
    }

    private void handlePlusMinus() {
    if (!readyToClear) {
    String txt = txtCalc.getText().toString();
    if (!txt.equals("0")) {
    if (txt.charAt(0) == '-')
    txt = txt.substring(1, txt.length());
    else
    txt = "-" + txt;

    txtCalc.setText(txt);
//  txtCalc.setSelection(txt.length());
    }
    }
    }

    private void reset() {
    num = 0;
    txtCalc.setText("0");
    //txtCalc.setSelection(1);
    operator = 1;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply store last operator as int. This way you can make `switch` to choose what operation must be performed as *last operation*.

Answer (score 0):

Try as folows

```
2 + 3 = 5.
When user hits "=",save 3 in a variable.In this case,
double tmp = 3;
whenever user press "="
just do the following 
num = num+tmp;
then show the result.
when user press another digit/symbol etc. then set tmp = 0;
```

Comment: But my mathematical operations are being performed using single operand only. And in this case it is "num" variable. Now how do I detect whether user has pressed the operator sign or number sign and how many times?

Comment: As how you detect user hits "=".

Comment: Here its sample code that I have tried:  "case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_EQUALS:
                            hasChanged = false;
                           if(!hasChanged && txtCalc.getText().toString()!= ""){
                    String strNum = txtCalc.getText().toString();
                    Double tmpNum = Double.valueOf(strNum);
                    handleEquals(keyCode);
                           }
                                  handleEquals(0);
                                  break;"

Answer (score 0):

You can detect "=" by following code, or you can use other keylisteners

```
txtCalc.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == 70) { 

                    Log.d("My Log"," = entered");
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }


        });
```

Here `KeyCode` 70 is the key code of '='

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, and i m getting keycodes by the use of {setOnKeyListeners(...)}. But the problem is, I stored the previous value in a temporary variable then also it is not doing anything. Here its sample code that I have tried: "case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_EQUALS:
  hasChanged = false;
  if(!hasChanged && txtCalc.getText().toString()!= ""){
   String strNum = txtCalc.getText().toString();
   Double tmpNum = Double.valueOf(strNum);
   handleEquals(keyCode);
  }
 handleEquals(0);
 break;"